# How to properly replace a dynamically imported module by a new one that has the same name but is defined at a different location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-importlib

For some context: I am currently trying to write a tool that automatically grades (over 100) submissions. Each submission comes in the form of a `solve.py` file that contains a `solve_exercise` function. Also, each submission is stored in a separate directory on my file system. The grading of a submission is done by calling `solve_exercise` on several exercises and checking the solution. After grading a submission, I want to go on to grade the next one. As such, I want to import a module named `solve` over a 100 times (once for each submission); however, each time, the module's implementation is to be fetched from a different location (and the previously used implementations are irrelevant and should be discarded or at least ignored). To speed up the process, I wanted to use multiprocessing.

Now, I have the following code, which, based on some testing, seems to work. However, I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing it and I am not accidentally introducing unwanted side effects or reusing the same `solve` implementation multiple times. (I tried to make the code below as minimal as possible and only include the things relevant to my question.)

```
def grade_submission(submission_dirpath : str, submission_identifier : str):
    submission_solve_module_filepath = os.path.join(submission_dirpath, "solve.py")

    # Import solve module
    submission_solve_module_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("solve", submission_solve_module_filepath)
    submission_solve_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(submission_solve_module_spec)
    sys.modules["solve"] = submission_solve_module
    submission_solve_module_spec.loader.exec_module(submission_solve_module)
    
    # Grade submission using imported solve module...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Parse command line arguments
    argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    argparser.add_argument("sdp", type=str, help="Path to directory that contains all submission directories.")
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    # Get subdirectories in submissions directory
    dir_path, subdir_names, _ = next(os.walk(args.sdp))

    # Construct list of argument tuples corresponding to submissions (i.e., the grade_submission function should be called once for each of these tuples)
    submission_arguments = []
    for subdir_name in subdir_names:
        # Create path to submission subdirectory
        subdir_path = os.path.join(dir_path, subdir_name)
        submission_arguments.append((subdir_path, subdir_name))

    # Parallelize grading
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(grade_submission, submission_arguments)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Is this a proper way of replacing the imported `solve` module each time a process proceeds to the next submission?

Comment: Why do you need to put `submission_solve_module` into the sys.modules dictionary?  It is already a Python object.  Its attributes can be accessed like those of any other object.  The function you want to test is simply `submission_solve_module.solve_exercise`, and is also a Python object that can be passed to another function, such as grade submission.  Since sys.modules is globally accessible, its use is problematic in a multiprocessing environment.  So why not just avoid it?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. Much appreciated! So, I got the way to do this from going through several related questions on this site and the `importlib` documentation ([from here, to be precise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly). However, I still lack a proper understanding of the whole mechanisms around importing. So you are saying I should already be okay with only the `submission_solve_module` object (not adding to `sys.modules`)? And during the creation of this object as is done now nothing then happens that may affect other processes?

Comment: I can think of no requirement to put every imported module into the sys.modules dictionary.  That is the "normal" practice, since the syntax `import solve` can later access the module (probably in a different source file).  Putting a module into sys.modules also means that it won't be garbage collected.  But that's not what you're trying to do here, so I see no reason why you can't just use the module like any other Python object.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for taking the time and effort to answer my question!